# How to properly initialize jQuery datatables api with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, datatables

I am trying to integrate the jQuery DataTables api with Vue.js. The data is loading and my action buttons seem to work fine for editing/updating but the table isn't being initialized properly as search doesn't work with the data and 'No data available in table' is appearing above the results. Vue.js is being loaded from a CDN within an ASP.NET MVC application (hence @@ in the markup to prevent conflicts with razor syntax). How should I properly initialize the data in the table:

What I have tried:
I have tried adding this.updateDataTable() within the fetch function and although that gets me a bit closer as the (no data' message isn't showing and search works - I get initialization warnings and the rows are duplicated (one with edit button and the initialized rows without).

Most of the examples I have found mix jQuery within the Vue instance and I thought this was bad practice? Although, I'm not sure it's completely unavoidable.

Markup:

```
<div id="app-datatable" class="container">
    <h3 class="mt-3">Add User</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>User ID</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="id" :disabled="editingIndex !== -1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>User name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name" :disabled="editingIndex === -1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>User Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="email" :disabled="editingIndex === -1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button v-if="editingIndex !== -1" class="btn btn-secondary" @@click="cancelEdit">Cancel</button>
            <button v-if="editingIndex !== -1" class="btn btn-success" @@click="updateUser">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-info mt-2" @@click="addUser">Add User</button>
    <hr>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table id="user-table" class="display table-bordered nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User ID</th>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>User Email</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(user, index) in dataTableData" :key="user.id">
                        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" @@click="editUser(index)">Edit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
const columns = [
    { title: 'User ID', data: 'id' },
    { title: 'User Name', data: 'name' },
    { title: 'User Email', data: 'email' },
    { title: 'Edit', orderable: false }
];

const columnDefs = [
    // Define columnDefs as needed
];
new Vue({
    el: '#app-datatable',
    data() {
        return {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            dataTableData: [],
            editingIndex: -1,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addUser() {
            this.dataTableData.push({
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name,
                email: this.email
            });
            this.clearForm();
        },

        editUser(index) {
            this.editingIndex = index;
            const user = this.dataTableData[index];
            this.id = user.id;
            this.name = user.name;
            this.email = user.email;
        },

        cancelEdit() {
            this.editingIndex = -1;
            this.clearForm();
        },

        updateUser() {
            if (this.editingIndex !== -1) {
                const user = this.dataTableData[this.editingIndex];
                user.id = this.id;
                user.name = this.name;
                user.email = this.email;
                this.cancelEdit();
            }
        },
        initializeDataTable() {
            this.dataTable = $('#user-table').DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "processing": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "retrieve": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "stateSave": false,
                "order": [],
                "columns": columns,
                "columnDefs": columnDefs
            });
        },
        fetchData() {
            const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
            fetch(url, {
                method: "GET",
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    response.json().then((data) => {
                        this.dataTableData = data
                    });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        },
        updateDataTable() {
            // Update DataTable with new data
            if (this.dataTable) {
                this.dataTable.clear().rows.add(this.dataTableData).draw();
            }
        },
        clearForm() {
            this.id = '';
            this.name = '';
            this.email = '';
        },

    },
    mounted() {
        this.initializeDataTable();
        this.fetchData();
    },
});
```

after more research, I have decided to abandon the use of jQuery Datatables with Vue. However, I did find a work around for this issue by implementing setTimeout within the initializeDataTable function:

```
initializeDataTable() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const dataTableData = $('#user-table').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "processing": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "retrieve": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "stateSave": false,
            "order": [],
            "columns": columns,
            "columnDefs": columnDefs
        });
    }, 300);
},
```

Comment: `mix jQuery within the Vue instance and I thought this was bad practice`  It is bad practice. Vue needs to manage the DOM while jQuery is directly manipulating it which leads to all kinds of conflicts.  The ideal solution here would be to use something that doesn't involve jQuery. If you absolutely need to, you can [make jQuery and Vue coexist](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/) by isolating them to different parts of your app.

Comment: @yoduh Thanks for the feedback. Looks like there is already [a wrapper for this api](https://datatables.net/manual/vue). Although, I think there are better alternatives and may look into Veutify.